# jasmine-jquery qUnit alternative

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, qunit, jasmine-jquery

I'm currently in the process of testing some Backbone.js views that are rendered using a template. My templates are defined in my html and built server-side using jinja. The unit test framework I'm using is qUnit. I'd like to be able to do something similar to the jasmine-jquery loadFixtures functionality, i.e., load my template into my test suite to be able to render my view (described here : http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/06/test-driving-backbone-views-with-jquery-templates-the-jasmine-gem-and-jasmine-jquery/ Jasmine-JQuery Fixtures To The Rescue! section).

Is there an alternative for qUnit ? A better way to proceeed ?

Here's how my views are defined :

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#my-template').html()),

  initialize: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template());
  }
});
```

And here's how I defined my template :

```
<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
    <div>
      <span>Bla bla</span>
    </div>
</script>
```